# Pyserial communication with Sparkfun Bluetooth mate only responding to one message

Tags: python, bluetooth, arduino, pyserial, serial-communication

I am building a robot using an Arduino Mega 2560 and a number of stepper motors and magnetic encoders to record its motion.

My environment is:

- Arduino Mega 2560
- Bluetooth Mate from Sparkfun
- Python 3.6.1
- Pyserial 2.7
- Windows 10

This is the code I am trying to use on the Python side:

```py
#This code is designed to test the communication between the python based code
#and a bluetooth mate connected to an Arduino Mega
# Author: Tynan Stack
# Date: July 24 2017
# Python 3.6.1 Pyserial 2.7

import serial
from time import sleep
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.port = 'COM7'
ser
ser.open()
sleep(8)
print("sending data")
ser.write(b'u\r\n')
print("data sent")
sleep(2)
ser.write(b"u\r\n")
sleep(8)

ser.close()
```

Here is the relevant portion of the Arduino code that handles the communication:

```cpp
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


  if(Serial3.available()){
    Serial.println("Its avalible");
    timer = micros();
    data = (char)Serial3.read();
    Serial.print(data);
    if(data == 'u'){//this corresponds to the linear stepper motor moving the stage up
      Linear.SpinTheMotor(LOW, 1.8,720);
    }
    if(data == 'd'){ //this corresponds to the linear stepper motor moving the stage down
      Linear.SpinTheMotor(HIGH, 1.8,720);
    }
    if (data == 'a'){
      Angular1.SpinTheMotor(LOW, 0.018, 15);
      Delays(micros(),1000);
      Angular1.SpinTheMotor(HIGH, 0.018, 15);
    }
    if(data == 'b'){
      Angular2.SpinTheMotor(LOW,0.018,15);
      Delays(micros(),1000);
      Angular2.SpinTheMotor(HIGH,0.018,15);
    }

  }
  if(digitalRead(BUTTONPIN)==LOW){
    BluetoothCycle();
    }
  bluetoothPrint();
}
```

For the other commands they either send commands to the stepper motor controllers or send data from the Mega to the Bluetooth chip to be received by the computer. There data is transferred from the Bluetooth chip to the computer fairly consistently while data from the computer to the chip is sparse normally only consisting of a single letter as can be seen in the code.

The issue that I am having is if I use a serial port connection software like Coolterm to connect to the Bluetooth chip everything works fine and I can send multiple commands to the Arduino to perform. However when I connect to the Bluetooth chip through my Python code only the first message is received and acted on by the Arduino. I have tried a variety of different solutions that have not worked yet. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem I was having was related to the Parameters used by pyserial. I needed to include the following declarations:

```
bluetoothconnection1.rtscts = 1
bluetoothconnection1.dsrdtr = 1
```

These enabled the hardware flow control which fixed my problem.